# Reading property of object of object

Tags: javascript, jquery

so if you have this html:

```
<li id='hi'></li>
```

and let's say this jquery:

```
var obj = {
    hi: {
        role:'something'
    },
    hello: {
       role: 'something'
   }
}


$('li').click(function(e) {
            var nameTrig = e.target.getAttribute('id');
            alert(obj.nameTrig.role);
});
```

I click the li => so if i call `obj.nameTrig.role`, it should be `'something'`?
I tried this and in the console it said: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Please help thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use bracket notation as the [member operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) to access a property where the property key is stored in a variable

```
alert(obj[nameTrig].role);
```

Also you can use `this.id` to access the clicked `li` elements id, `e.target.id` will give wrong results if you have another element within the `li` and you click on it

```
$('li').click(function (e) {
    var nameTrig = this.id;
    alert(obj[nameTrig]role);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need the *bracket notation style* to accomplish this.

```
alert(obj[ nameTrig ].role);
```